# DomPDF: Error with '2+' 'term_user' entries while generating certificates

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, dompdf

I want to generate certificates even when I have 2 or more data entries.
I'm using DomPDF to generate certificates. When the 'term_user' pivot table has a '1' data, there's no error in generating certificates. However, when there are '2' or more data entries, I get an error. I suspect the problem is with this line of code: '$term = Term::find($termId);' as it returns nul

This is my CertificateController to generate certificates:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Certificate;
use App\Models\Term;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF as DomPDFPDF;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth as FacadesAuth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

class CertificateController extends Controller
{
    public function generateCertificate($termId)
    {

        // Fetch the term and relevant data
        

       // Get the authenticated user
        $user = FacadesAuth::user();
        // Get the authenticated user's name
        $userName = FacadesAuth::user()->name;
        $userLastName = FacadesAuth::user()->last_name;
        $usermiddleinitial = FacadesAuth::user()->middle_initial;

        // Fetch the certificate data, including the logo URL
        $term = Term::find($termId);
        dd($term);
        //if (!$term) {
        //    return response()->json(['error' => 'Term not found.'], 404);
       // }
        $certificate = Certificate::first();

        $termUser = $term->users()->where('user_id', $user->id)->first();
        $finishDate = $termUser->pivot->finish_date;

        // Prepare data for the certificate template
        $data = [
            'username' => $userName,
            'userlastname' => $userLastName,
            'usermiddleinitial' => $usermiddleinitial,
            'course' => $term->course->title,
            'term' => $term->title,
            'date' => $finishDate,
            'logo' => base64_encode(file_get_contents(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'logo' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($certificate->logo)))),
            'position_1' => $certificate->position_1, 
            'position_2' => $certificate->position_2, 
            'name_1' => $certificate->name_1, 
            'name_2' => $certificate->name_2,
            'signature_1' => base64_encode(file_get_contents(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'signatures1' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($certificate->signature_1)))),
            'signature_2' => base64_encode(file_get_contents(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'signatures2' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($certificate->signature_2)))),
            'background' => base64_encode(file_get_contents(storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'background' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . basename($certificate->background)))),
        ];
        
       

        // Load the certificate template HTML
        $html = view('certificate.certificate', $data)->render();

        // Generate the PDF from the HTML
        $pdf = PDF::loadHTML($html);

        // Set the paper size to certificate size (e.g., A4) and landscape orientation
        $pdf->setPaper('Letter', 'landscape');

        // Set the file name for the PDF
        $fileName = 'certificate_' . $term->id . '.pdf';

        // Optionally, you can store the PDF on the server or force download
        // Example: $pdf->save(storage_path('certificates/' . $fileName));
        // Example: return $pdf->download($fileName);

        // Display the PDF in the browser
        return $pdf->stream($fileName);
    }
    // Method to handle the form submission
    public function index()
    {
        $certificate = Certificate::first(); // Retrieve a single certificate
        return view('contents.admin.badges.index', compact('certificate'));
    }
}
```

My route for generating certificates:

```
 Route::get('/generate-certificate/{term}', [CertificateController::class,'generateCertificate'])->name('generate.certificate');
```

My view to generate certificates:

```
<p class="text-dark">
<i class="fa fa-check-circle text-success"></i>
<a href="{{ route('generate.certificate', ['term' => $term->id]) }}" target="_blank">Print Certificate</a>
</p>
```